# Antdesign tabs react router navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, antd

I am trying to do tabs with has navigation but When I go back tabs are not changing. for instance, I move to tab2 and then click go back. content and active tab not change.

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-bush-bozr6)

Anyone has an idea?

**- Solution -**

Solution added to example. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The defaultActiveKey is just on initial load. Use active key instead.

```
    <Tabs
      activeKey={(match.params.source ? match.params.source : "")}
      onChange={(key) => {
        history.push(`/${key}`);
      }}
      tabBarGutter={10}
    >
      <TabPane tab="tab1" key="">
        <p>TabPane1</p>
      </TabPane>
      <TabPane tab="tab2" key="tab2">
        <p>TabPane2</p>
      </TabPane>
    </Tabs>
```

Note: due to the fact that match.params.source is undefined initially I had to add that check in activeKey to set the default to "" when its not set.

- the switch is not necessary in page.js.

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify a key param to the `<TabPane />` component since you use it on the onChange handler.
If you don't, you'll see `null` in the url. Something like this : `https://blablabla/null`
since you declared the route like `<Route path={"/:source?"} component={page} exact={false} />`
In the other hand, you don't have to specify another Switch component inside the `page.js` file, since you specify it on the Parent (`App.js`)

**Here's the working code:**

page.js

```
     <Tabs
        defaultActiveKey={match.params.source}
        onChange={(key) => {
          history.push(`/${key}`);
        }}
        tabBarGutter={10}
      >
        <TabPane tab="tab1" key="tab1">
          <p>TabPane1</p>
        </TabPane>
        <TabPane tab="tab2" key="tab2">
          <p>TabPane2</p>
        </TabPane>
      </Tabs>
```

app.js

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path={"/:source?"} component={page} exact={false} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to first tab on the '/' url. I don't additional path on the tab1.